# Oracle select string to boolean in select statement

Tags: oracle

I am new to Oracle :)

I have this statement has a string value called **Active**. The value can be **Y** or **N**. I want to do a select statement that returns a boolean value for that field.
Currently it looks like this:

```
select h.catalogueid    ID,
    h.cataloguename     NAME,
    h.uniquecatalogue   INCLUDEPRODUCTS,
    h.active            ACTIVE,
    h.ownbrandedlabels  OWNLABELS            
from cc_ob_catalogueheader h
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
select h.catalogueid    ID,
    h.cataloguename     NAME,
    h.uniquecatalogue   INCLUDEPRODUCTS,
    h.active = 'Y'      ACTIVE,
    h.ownbrandedlabels  OWNLABELS            
from cc_ob_catalogueheader h
```

But that is syntaxly incorrect. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Oracle does not support booleans at the SQL level (but do support them at PL/SQL level)

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean that, as far as the Oracle SQL engine is concerned, boolean values are not supported and you're stuck with 'Y'/'N', 0/1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this myself.
I changed my select statement to this:

```
select h.catalogueid                                ID,
    h.cataloguename                                 NAME,
    h.uniquecatalogue                               INCLUDEPRODUCTS,
    CASE WHEN (h.active = 'Y') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END    ACTIVE,
    h.ownbrandedlabels                              OWNLABELS
from cc_ob_catalogueheader h
```

Comment: You did not solve your issue, you still don't have a boolean value but a numeric value